# How to get response status code on process_exception in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, exception, scrapy, scrapy-middleware

I want to retry Scrapy request when if it gets an exception and the response status code is 429. The problem is I don't know how to get the response status on the `process_exception`. How can I do it since it seems there is no way to access response object inside `process_exception`?

```
class FakeUserAgentErrorRetryMiddleware(RetryMiddleware):

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        if type(exception) == FakeUserAgentError: return self._retry(request, exception, spider)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retry a request when you have `response.status = 429`
 you should add 429 in **[RETRY_HTTP_CODES](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-http-codes)**

```
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [429]
```

You can set also set the maximum number of times to retry with [RETRY_TIMES](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-times)

Comment: That doesn't work on Scrapy Splash, so I wanted to try this way

Comment: You didn't mention that you use Splash :)

Comment: I mention it now

Comment: it's better to mention it in your question for getting right answer faster :)